# Calling Microsoft Graph from Taskpane Outlook plugin

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I have successfully managed to configure my plugin (and Azure app registration) for SSO, such that `Office.auth.getAccessToken()` returns an access token.

However, I cannot use this access token with Microsoft Graph.  I get an error saying the audience is incorrect.

I know there is a way of using an intermediate web API server to call MS Graph (which I do not really want to do and have not investigated yet).  Is there a way to simply call the Microsoft Graph API directly from the plugin using SSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token returned by Office.auth.getAccessToken() does not give access to Microsoft Graph. It provides access to the add-in's own server-side APIs.
The server-side code should use the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) to request a new access token with permissions to Microsoft Graph.
Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/ad-ins/outlook/authentication to know about other authentication options on Outlook add-ins depending upon the use case.

Comment: But why do I need a server just to call Graph? For example, I want to get the content of multiple selected emails. I can only do this via Graph, I cannot get the content directly via the office.js API.  Are you saying that the only way to do this is by deploying my own server?

Comment: FYI, I did eventually just implement my own server to do this.  However, I now have another problem - please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77656916/getaccesstoken-fails-in-outlook-plugin-with-error-13006