# getAccessToken fails in Outlook plugin with error 13006

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was previously able to call `Office.auth.getAccessToken` in the Outlook 365 client from a taskpane plugin. However, I have switched to the 'new' Outlook and this call always fails with error `13006`.

As an alternative, I have tried the display dialog method discussed in the documentation. This works fine but it constantly asks the user for permission to open the authentication dialog box.  This is clearly not acceptable.

Is there a reason why `getAccessToken` doesn't work in the new Outlook?

Comment: A similar issue has been posted here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3921 . Please follow the same for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed now:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3921